# How to specify multiple observations per participant in mlogit in R?

Tags: r, mlogit

I am conducting a multinomial regression using r package `mlogit`. All my independent variables are  patient-specific (age, sex, etc), and not choice-specific. So my model looks like this:

```
mlogit(outcome ~ 0 | age+Gender+comorbidities)
```

I have some patients who had multiple observations, so I formatted the data with 3 indices:

```
dfidx(data, shape = 'wide', choice = outcome, 
      idx=list(c("choiceid", "Participant_ID")))
```

However, I see that the results are identical regardless of whether the data is formatted with 3 indices or 2 indices (2 indices being choice and choiceid, but no participant ID). How can I modify the model formula to include `participant_ID`?

I considered using the `rpar` specification but I think it is only for choice-varying variables, so I cannot use it to specify `participant_ID`